# Binding Custom Event To Angular Element

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to create collapsible component, for which I prefer to bind a custom event toggle to the html element.

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="content.toggle()">Toggle Content</button>
<div #content appCollapse class="border border-slate-200 p-5 my-5">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Culpa nam qui ipsa asperiores minus tempora!Velit accusantium asperiores maxime nisi amet veniam in, aliquam, id sequi at ullam natus dolore.
</div>
```

I am getting below error

```
error TS2551: Property 'toggle' does not exist on type 'HTMLDivElement'. Did you mean 'ontoggle'?
```

For testing purpose, I changed to event click and is working as expected.

```
 <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="content.click()">Toggle Content</button>
```

**app-collapse.directive.ts**

```
constructor(el:ElementRef) {
    this.el = el;
    this.el.nativeElement.classList.add('collapse');

    this.el.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('toggle'));
    this.el.nativeElement.addEventListener('toggle', ()=>{
      this.el.nativeElement.classList.toggle('show');
    });
    this.el.nativeElement.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
      this.el.nativeElement.classList.toggle('show');
    });
   }
```

How to bind a custom event to html element.

**Reproducable code**

```js
const el  = document.getElementById('el');

el.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('toggle', {}));

el.addEventListener('click', function(){
console.log("click working")
});
el.addEventListener('toggle', function(){
console.log("toggle working")
});

function onButtonClick(){
el.click();
}
function onButtonToggle(){
el.toggle();
}
```

```html
<div id="el">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Vitae excepturi porro rerum aspernatur a impedit quaerat magni quam aliquid molestiae eos illum maxime deserunt, veniam sequi rem ipsum ducimus hic.
</div>

<button onclick="onButtonClick()">Click</button>
<button onclick="onButtonToggle()">Toggle</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referring to [ngBootstrap](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/blob/master/src/collapse/collapse.ts) solved the issue.

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appCollapse]',
  exportAs: 'appCollapse'   // added this line
})
export class CollapseDirective {
 
  el!:ElementRef;
  
  constructor(el:ElementRef) {
    this.el = el;
    this.el.nativeElement.classList.add('collapse');
   }

   toggle(){
    this.el.nativeElement.classList.toggle('show');
  }


}
```

And in html

```
 <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="content.toggle()">Toggle Content</button>
 <div #content="appCollapse" appCollapse  class="border border-slate-200 p-5 my-5">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Culpa nam qui ipsa asperiores minus tempora!Velit accusantium asperiores maxime nisi amet veniam in, aliquam, id sequi at ullam natus dolore.
 </div>
```